# ngAnimate removeClass not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, ng-animate

I have been working with the ngAnimate module for AngularJS 1.2.14

When I use $animate.addClass it works correctly adding the ng-animate, -add, -add-active

However when I use $animate.removeClass it seems to just run the equivalent of elem.removeClass.  None of the animation classes are applied on the remove (such as ng-animate, -remove, -remove-active)

Here is the plnkr replicating the issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DIQSthOFxooVDSqO2KKQ?p=preview

I can code the remove methods manually but I would prefer to use the Animate directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the transition on the element's class itself, not on the class you are adding/animating.

That way `$animate` will look at the class and realise it has a transition applied, and animate accordingly. Otherwise it doesn't bother adding/removing classes as it would all happen at the same time.

See [my fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/988p7O9dEIHvLMqHzNXZ?p=preview)

**CSS Classes used**:

```
.classname {
  // The class of the element you want to animate
  // Its default state (invisible).

}

.classname.visible-class-add {
  // Any preparatory work you need to do before animating
  // This is the ideal place to put your transition property.
}

.classname.visible-class-add-active{
  // during-animation class (often none needed)
}

.classname.visible-class-remove {
  // Pre- remove class: possibly the same as .visible-class-add
}

.classname.visible-class-remove-active {
  // any during-animation style (often none required)
}

.classname.visible-class {
  // The visible state.
}
```

Comment: This solution works.  However it does not seem to follow the documentation style. http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate  This shows ng-animate class being applied for both the add and remove methods.

Comment: if you inspect the card, the `ng-animate` class *is* being displayed both times. To make it slower change the transition duration and it'll be easier to see.

Your CSS is odd though, I will edit to show the classes you should have

Comment: Is there a reason attaching the actually transition code the the `ng-animate` is not working? like this: `.ng-animate {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
}`

Comment: Yes there is - angular doesn't look for css animations in an `ng-animate`. That class is used for javascript animations. As such, if your transition code is in there, then angular thinks you haven't defined any transitions for that element.

Comment: handy link: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

Comment: Yeah I have been using that it is a great resource. I was just playing with this some more and came to the same conclusion you typed above :-) http://plnkr.co/edit/CgqylSGemIYVgBL5H2kR?p=preview  Thanks!

Comment: good job. I have to re-read that article every time I look at animation! It's not that intuitive.